# Adobe CQ AEM selectionchanged listeners variable access in JSP

Tags: jsp, variables, aem, listeners

I have the following code inside a listener on a selection widget.

```
function(box){
    var parent = box.findParentByType('panel');
    if (this.getValue()=="calloutStandard"){
        parent.findByType('textfield')[4].setVisible(true);
        parent.findByType('textfield')[4].allowBlank=false;
    }else if(this.getValue()=="calloutSpotlight"){
        parent.findByType('textfield')[4].setVisible(true);
        parent.findByType('textfield')[4].allowBlank=false;
    }else if(this.getValue()=="calloutMini"){
        parent.findByType('textfield')[4].setVisible(false);
        parent.findByType('textfield')[4].allowBlank=true;
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to grab the `this.getValue()` and use it in my jsp for the webpage. That way I can create an if/else to show different html based on what the value is.

How would I go about passing a variable from here into my JSP, or access variables set here from my JSP?

Edit: Solution found. Blatantly obvious. The name on the selection in the component is `calloutType` so I was able to gather the value by using a simple `String calloutType = properties.get("calloutType", "");`. Thank you @SharathMadappa

Comment: This is javascript right, so the answer is obviously Ajax.

Comment: @developerwjk Would you be able to poing me in the right direction of how I would use Ajax to make this happen? I've not worked with Ajax yet and know nothing about what I'd be doing with it. I'm thinking I need to write a function in the JSP that will somehow call out to this script to grab those values.

Comment: the value will be stored on the node when the content editor saves the changes right ? can't you fetch it in the components jsp from the implicit properties object ?

Comment: @SharathMadappa Thank you for the pointer. I don't know what I was doing wrong earlier. I tried this same method before, but I was getting blanks. After I started messing with it and getting errors, I seem to have gotten it all put together. String calloutType = properties.get("calloutType", "");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time I posted this, I was unable to submit answers. I can now. So cleaning up some old questions. Here is the answer:

Solution found. Blatantly obvious. The name on the selection in the component is calloutType so I was able to gather the value by using a simple

```
String calloutType = properties.get("calloutType", "");
```

Thank you @SharathMadappa